# javascript string replace with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I got a problem with javascript RegExp. I want to replace the `a.href` with `textbox` value when I click on the button.But, I don't want to replace the whole string just want to find and replace those are exact match with my RegExp. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnRun').click(function(){
        var str = encodeURIComponent($('#mydata').val());
        var regExp = new RegExp('\\b' +encodeURIComponent( $('a').html()) + '\\b','gi');
        $('a').attr('href',$('a').attr('href').replace(regExp,str));
    });
});
```

this is my test code
http://jsfiddle.net/4uAp5/1/

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you need a regex to do that. This code should accomplish what you are describing:

```
$('a').attr('href',$("#mydata").val());
```

Also worth noting is that the way you are targeting the link – `$('a')` – will select *every* link on the page...

Comment: That will replace the entire `href` value, but he apparently only wants to replace the matched part.

Answer (score 1):

`\\b` does not match because the href value is encoded and results (in this specific example) in `cMyTest1`.  `c` does not satisfy `\\b`.  There are a variety of solutions depending upon specific circumstances.  One is to use `decodeURI` on the href first before using the regex and then encode it later (although it's probably not needed).

http://jsfiddle.net/4uAp5/4/

Comment: As I tested, there have some problem with Unicode character such as Chinese character.